# w3 Total Cache not Caching - Requested URI is rejected

Tags: plugins, cache, performance, plugin-w3-total-cache

For some reason Total Cache does seem to be caching my pages.

Each time I got to a page, when I view source, the Total Cache comment shows that it regenerated the page for this request.

What worse, it seems to be regenerating the combined/minified css and js files for each request as well! This alone adds another 5sec to the already 4sec the page takes to load.

So I turned on debugging and this is what I am seeing:

```
W3 Total Cache: Page cache debug info:
Engine: disk: basic
Cache key: w3tc_site.com_1_page_e251273eb74a8ee3f661a7af00915af1
Caching: disabled            //PROBLEM
Reject reason: Requested URI is rejected           //PROBLEM
Status: not cached           //PROBLEM
Creation Time: 0.634s
Header info:
X-Pingback: http://site.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.4

Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: http://www.w3-edge.com/wordpress-plugins/

Minified using disk: basic
Database Caching 6/6 queries in 0.011 seconds using disk: basic
Object Caching 608/613 objects using disk: basic

Served from: site.com @ 2011-09-18 17:47:24
```

Any ideas what could be going on hear?

Update:

For the record, if it makes a difference, the site is being hosted on IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the settings set to an option your hosting provider doesn't allow?

Or maybe you don't have the .htaccess configured correctly to allow the plugin to work as required.

Did you try the default or "automatic" set-up to see if the error is generated?

Comment: Pretty much everything is at default and I haven't manually touched my .htaccess. If it makes a difference I'm using IIS 7 as my web host.

Comment: When you set it up did it ask you to make certain permission/re-write changes, or do you recall if you chose to allow the plug-in to make them automatically.

Comment: No I don't remember it asking me anything like that. Is there a folder that I should check or a way of verifying if the permissions are all setup correctly? I do remember I had trouble, enabling the plugin when I first added it, but it didn't have a specific error. After trying to enable it  few time it just worked.

Comment: It requires temporary access to the wp-content directory. It changes it from 755 to 705, and must me changed back manually. It also adds a ton of code to the .htaccess file (required to function correctly). If you go to Performance>Install, it will show you an extensive list of files that needed changed. You might check the .htaccess file at least to ensure it's been configured correctly.

Comment: Does it make a difference that I am running IIS? Under IIS I don't think I have .htaccess.

Comment: I'm sure it matters. I'm not sure for IIS. I've set up a few sites using IIS7, but I'm not familiar with it enough to advise. When you go to the FAQ's or the Install section of the plugin admin, does it give any info that you can use?

Comment: On the FAQ it says that IIS is supported. But I'm not sure where it puts what it normally might put in the .httpaccess

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in the latest version of the plugin.

Other users have reported the same issue on the WordPress.org forums - http://wordpress.org/tags/w3-total-cache?forum_id=10

Frederick Townes, the plugin author, has suggested that users try the latest development version of the plugin, which can be downloaded at http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/w3-total-cache.zip

Comment: Thanks for the response. One of the question on that is me. Just wanting to verify, are you sure thats the dev/test version? It looks like the same url that is where the released version would be and the version is the same as the released version, 0.9.2.4, which is the one I am having trouble with.

Comment: The current release is 0.9.2.4, which can be downloaded at a different url  http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/w3-total-cache.0.9.2.4.zip . You can find a complete  version list at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/download/ . The development version can be found at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use W3 Total Cache plugin on my [WordPress Blog](http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/). My blog is running on Windows Server. I had similar problems to yours. Even though the plugin says that it works on Windows servers, it still have issues.

My solution was to discontinue using the W3 Total Cache plugin, and try simpler caching plugins (like [Super cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) or other ones).

In windows servers the permission is set by your hosting provider and not like in Linux servers where the user can change the permissions.
My advice is don't waste your time trying to run W3 Total cache on Windows servers, or at least use the very basic features of the plugin, or use other plugins. Or find other ways to speed the page load time.